# Server 2008R2 : DNS Server registering multiple IPs for DNS Server itself

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vmware-workstation, windows-dns

Hi I have installed Active Directory with Local DNS Server
IPv4 only no IPv6

Local Area Connection
IP is 192.168.1.101

but it also has VMWare Workstation 9 Installed Locally
which created two VMWare Network Adapter VMNet1 and VMNet8

VMNet1 
192.168.88.1

VMNet8
192.168.174.1

When i look inside my DNS Manager i see three entries for this server
for all these 3 IPs

my VMNet1 and 8 doesn't have DNS Server Entries they are blank
only Local Area Connection has my DNS Server Address.

How can i fix this issue to keep only one entry?
which is coming from Local Area Connection

Regards

Comment: Why do you have vmware workstation installed on an active-directory server? You should really keep this seperate.

Comment: This is my home lab i have 3 servers all of them have VMware Workstation. It helps me run move VMs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting for this:

**DNS PubishAddresses setting**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959753.aspx

Key: HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNS\Parameters
Value:  PubishAddresses

Specifies the IP addresses you want to publish for the computer. The Domain Name System (DNS) server creates A (address) records only for the addresses in this list.

If this entry does not appear in the registry, or if its value is blank, *the DNS server creates an A record for each of the computer's IP addresses.*

This entry is designed for computers with multiple IP addresses, where you prefer to publish only a subset of the available addresses. Typically, this is used to prevent the DNS server from returning a private network address in response to a query, when the computer has a corporate network address.

Activation method

DNS reads its registry entries only when it starts. You can change entries while the DNS server is running by using the DNS console. If you change entries by editing the registry, the changes are not effective until you restart the DNS server.

Comment: i followed these instructions http://support.microsoft.com/kb/292822   Edit menu, point to New, and then click String Value to add the following registry value:
Value name: PublishAddresses

Comment: bounced my server after the changes and only one entry now

Comment: Million thanks for the help, you saved me lot of time because of this issue many time my VMs would stop resolving because of issue on the DNS Server resolution too and i had to manually delete the two entries and restart DNS Server. I am glad i found this forum. you guys are awesome